# How to prevent a column of numbers from being inserted into first column of dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a file that looks like this (file 1):

```
number variant_id gene_id tss_distance ma_samples ma_count maf pval_nominal slope slope_se hg38_chr hg38_pos ref_allele alt_allele hg19_chr hg19_pos ID new_MAF CHROM POS REF ALT A1 OBS_CT BETA SE P SD Variance 
6253443 chr1_17726150_G_A_b38 ENSG00000272426.1 821374 68 78 0.0644628 0.764314 -0.0320846 0.106958 chr1 17726150 G A chr1 18052645 rs260514:18052645:G:A 0.058155 1 18052645 G A G 1597 0.0147047 0.0656528 0.822804 2.62364886486368 6.88353336610048
6253444 chr1_17726150_G_A_b38 ENSG00000117118.9 671980 68 78 0.0644628 0.955989 -0.00275742 0.0499406 chr1 17726150 G A chr1 18052645 rs260514:18052645:G:A 0.058155 1 18052645 G A G 1597 0.0147047 0.0656528 0.822804 2.62364886486368 6.88353336610048
```

I want to get rid of the number column (first col) so I do the command below which correctly removes the number column.

```
Data <- read.table("/filepath_to_file/file1.txt", header = TRUE)
Data <- subset(Data, select = -number)
write.table(Data, "/filepath_to_file/file2.txt")
```

However, I always get another column inserted with values inserted in the first column with no column name and random speech marks. As a result, because it has no header and random values in column 1, the column names have shifted once to the right meaning the values don't align to the correct column name. How can I get rid of this extra inserted column with numbers and the random speech marks. File 2:

```
"variant_id" "gene_id" "tss_distance" "ma_samples" "ma_count" "maf" "pval_nominal" "slope" "slope_se" "hg38_chr" "hg38_pos" "ref_allele" "alt_allele" "hg19_chr" "hg19_pos" "ID" "new_MAF" "CHROM" "POS" "REF" "ALT" "A1" "OBS_CT" "BETA" "SE" "P" "SD" "Variance"
"1" "chr1_17726150_G_A_b38" "ENSG00000272426.1" 821374 68 78 0.0644628 0.764314 -0.0320846 0.106958 "chr1" 17726150 "G" "A" "chr1" 18052645 "rs260514:18052645:G:A" 0.058155 1 18052645 "G" "A" "G" 1597 0.0147047 0.0656528 0.822804 2.62364886486368 6.88353336610048
"2" "chr1_17726150_G_A_b38" "ENSG00000117118.9" 671980 68 78 0.0644628 0.955989 -0.00275742 0.0499406 "chr1" 17726150 "G" "A" "chr1" 18052645 "rs260514:18052645:G:A" 0.058155 1 18052645 "G" "A" "G" 1597 0.0147047 0.0656528 0.822804 2.62364886486368 6.88353336610048
```

Is there a way just to get the output to look like this.

```
variant_id gene_id tss_distance ma_samples ma_count maf pval_nominal slope slope_se hg38_chr hg38_pos ref_allele alt_allele hg19_chr hg19_pos ID new_MAF CHROM POS REF ALT A1 OBS_CT BETA SE P SD Variance 
chr1_17726150_G_A_b38 ENSG00000272426.1 821374 68 78 0.0644628 0.764314 -0.0320846 0.106958 chr1 17726150 G A chr1 18052645 rs260514:18052645:G:A 0.058155 1 18052645 G A G 1597 0.0147047 0.0656528 0.822804 2.62364886486368 6.88353336610048
chr1_17726150_G_A_b38 ENSG00000117118.9 671980 68 78 0.0644628 0.955989 -0.00275742 chr1 17726150 G A chr1 18052645 rs260514:18052645:G:A 0.058155 1 18052645 G A G 1597 0.0147047 0.0656528 0.822804 2.62364886486368 6.88353336610048
```

I should say this has happened a number of times whenever I run a command on my dataframe to tweak it. I get random numbers inserted in the first column with no header meaning the values get misaligned to the column names. Any help will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add `row.names=FALSE` (and `quote=FALSE`) to your call to `write.table`.

```r
write.table(quux)
# "variant_id" "gene_id" "tss_distance" "ma_samples" "ma_count" "maf" "pval_nominal" "slope" "slope_se" "hg38_chr" "hg38_pos" "ref_allele" "alt_allele" "hg19_chr" "hg19_pos" "ID" "new_MAF" "CHROM" "POS" "REF" "ALT" "A1" "OBS_CT" "BETA" "SE" "P" "SD" "Variance"
# "1" "chr1_17726150_G_A_b38" "ENSG00000272426.1" 821374 68 78 0.0644628 0.764314 -0.0320846 0.106958 "chr1" 17726150 "G" "A" "chr1" 18052645 "rs260514:18052645:G:A" 0.058155 1 18052645 "G" "A" "G" 1597 0.0147047 0.0656528 0.822804 2.62364886486368 6.88353336610048
# "2" "chr1_17726150_G_A_b38" "ENSG00000117118.9" 671980 68 78 0.0644628 0.955989 -0.00275742 0.0499406 "chr1" 17726150 "G" "A" "chr1" 18052645 "rs260514:18052645:G:A" 0.058155 1 18052645 "G" "A" "G" 1597 0.0147047 0.0656528 0.822804 2.62364886486368 6.88353336610048

write.table(quux, quote = FALSE)
# variant_id gene_id tss_distance ma_samples ma_count maf pval_nominal slope slope_se hg38_chr hg38_pos ref_allele alt_allele hg19_chr hg19_pos ID new_MAF CHROM POS REF ALT A1 OBS_CT BETA SE P SD Variance
# 1 chr1_17726150_G_A_b38 ENSG00000272426.1 821374 68 78 0.0644628 0.764314 -0.0320846 0.106958 chr1 17726150 G A chr1 18052645 rs260514:18052645:G:A 0.058155 1 18052645 G A G 1597 0.0147047 0.0656528 0.822804 2.62364886486368 6.88353336610048
# 2 chr1_17726150_G_A_b38 ENSG00000117118.9 671980 68 78 0.0644628 0.955989 -0.00275742 0.0499406 chr1 17726150 G A chr1 18052645 rs260514:18052645:G:A 0.058155 1 18052645 G A G 1597 0.0147047 0.0656528 0.822804 2.62364886486368 6.88353336610048

write.table(quux, row.names = FALSE)
# "variant_id" "gene_id" "tss_distance" "ma_samples" "ma_count" "maf" "pval_nominal" "slope" "slope_se" "hg38_chr" "hg38_pos" "ref_allele" "alt_allele" "hg19_chr" "hg19_pos" "ID" "new_MAF" "CHROM" "POS" "REF" "ALT" "A1" "OBS_CT" "BETA" "SE" "P" "SD" "Variance"
# "chr1_17726150_G_A_b38" "ENSG00000272426.1" 821374 68 78 0.0644628 0.764314 -0.0320846 0.106958 "chr1" 17726150 "G" "A" "chr1" 18052645 "rs260514:18052645:G:A" 0.058155 1 18052645 "G" "A" "G" 1597 0.0147047 0.0656528 0.822804 2.62364886486368 6.88353336610048
# "chr1_17726150_G_A_b38" "ENSG00000117118.9" 671980 68 78 0.0644628 0.955989 -0.00275742 0.0499406 "chr1" 17726150 "G" "A" "chr1" 18052645 "rs260514:18052645:G:A" 0.058155 1 18052645 "G" "A" "G" 1597 0.0147047 0.0656528 0.822804 2.62364886486368 6.88353336610048

write.table(quux, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
# variant_id gene_id tss_distance ma_samples ma_count maf pval_nominal slope slope_se hg38_chr hg38_pos ref_allele alt_allele hg19_chr hg19_pos ID new_MAF CHROM POS REF ALT A1 OBS_CT BETA SE P SD Variance
# chr1_17726150_G_A_b38 ENSG00000272426.1 821374 68 78 0.0644628 0.764314 -0.0320846 0.106958 chr1 17726150 G A chr1 18052645 rs260514:18052645:G:A 0.058155 1 18052645 G A G 1597 0.0147047 0.0656528 0.822804 2.62364886486368 6.88353336610048
# chr1_17726150_G_A_b38 ENSG00000117118.9 671980 68 78 0.0644628 0.955989 -0.00275742 0.0499406 chr1 17726150 G A chr1 18052645 rs260514:18052645:G:A 0.058155 1 18052645 G A G 1597 0.0147047 0.0656528 0.822804 2.62364886486368 6.88353336610048
```

Comment: its always safe to use `quote = TRUE` eg if a cell has a value like `today is good` without the quote,  reading it back in will try to put the text into three columns instead of 1

Comment: `write.table(quux, quote=TRUE)` includes quotes around many of the elements, and the OP's expected output includes no quotes, so I went with false. I agree that it is risky in the possible presence of embedded spaces @onyambu